# C# overload byte error

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a function that supports 4 parameters, but it does not work..
How I can resolve this ?
Thank you.

```
private void Byte(byte a, byte b, uint c, byte d)
{
     PS3.SetMemory(a + b * c, new byte[] { d });
}

Byte(0x00f474e3 + 0x3700 * dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index, new byte[] { 0x03 });
```

Error:

> ```
> Error: No overload for 'Byte' method takes two arguments
> ```

Comment: Error message isn't clear? Your `Byte` method takes `4` parameter but you try to call it with `2` arguments. One with `(0x00f474e3 + 0x3700 * dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index` and another is `new byte[] { 0x03 }`

Comment: well your second parameter is a NON byte array but you are trying to pass a byte array. furthermore your 3rd and 4th parameter are not specified.

Comment: And in addition: of course a byte[] is not a byte.

Answer (score 5):

You dont need to perform the calculations while sending the parameters.

I Think you wanted to do this:

```
Byte(0x00f474e3,0x3700 , dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index , 0x03);
```

**OR**

You can simply avoid Byte() function by wrting asbelow:

```
PS3.SetMemory(0x00f474e3 + 0x3700 * dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index, 
                                                            new byte[] { 0x03 });
```

Answer (score 1):

### The error says it all.

Yes. You're not specifying `c` and `d`.

`0x00f474e3 + 0x3700 * dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index` is `a`

while

`new byte[] { 0x03 }` is `b`, which is wrong. It doesn't expect byte array but just byte.

What about `c`, `d`?

So, I think you should do:

```
Byte(0x00f474e3,0x3700,dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index,0x03);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass parameters as is:

```
Byte(0x00f474e3, 0x3700, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index, 0x03);
```